# Is using a singularity sandbox an effective way to increase security through isolation / compartmentalization?

Tags: sandbox, container, isolation, firejail

I am using singularity sandboxes in my workflow for several reasons unrelated to security. However, after using it a bit, I am now wondering: is using a singularity sandbox an effective way to increase security by enforcing isolation / compartmentalization / an effective "sandboxing for security purposes" solution?

Typically, if I create a singularity sandbox with:

```
singularity build --fakeroot --sandbox singularity_sandbox docker://ubuntu:22.04
```

and I then open a shell into it with:

```
singularity shell --writable --fakeroot --no-home --net --network none singularity_sandbox/
```

Then it looks so far to me like I now have a shell into an Ubuntu22.04 singularity sandbox that cannot access any file outside of its folder and cannot use the network. Of course, depending on my need I can actively decide to (carefully) use `--network` to open the network a bit (giving just the necessary accesses), and `--bind` to give access to a small subset of host files if needed.

If I do so, how does the security model compare to using other isolation tools, such as firejail, or a full VMWare VM? In particular, if I install and run programs I do not trust in such a singularity sandbox, being careful to not give access to any files or networks from the host that are sensitive, am I (and in particular is my trusted host) at any risk?

If the comparison with firejail depends on the kind of use of firejail, we can assume that I am able to run the application with firejail in `--appimage` mode, i.e. including the `--nonewprivs` flag - if this has anything to say for the comparison. In addition, I will use either `--private` or `--private=SOME_DIR` to restrict access to my user filesystem.

Comment: It took me some time to find the technical details, but it looks like maybe firejail and singularity have the same typical security considerations applying. Firejail is a well known setuid program (this is very visible by reading about it on the net). Actually, I think singularity leverages the exact same kind of technology (this was not as obvious to me by reading on the net at first): see: https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.11/user-guide/security.html ... [continue below]

Comment: ... [continuation of above] "In a default installation, SingularityCE uses a setuid starter binary to perform only the specific tasks needed to setup the container.".  However: "Newer distributions have support for ‘unprivileged user namespace creation’. This means a normal user can create a user namespace, in which most setup operations needed to run a container can be run, unprivileged." . But "the default mode of operation of SingularityCE uses a setuid binary". So that may depend on the install / host kernel / config too?